# Cannot debug executable with lldb on macOS M1: attach failed ((os/kern) invalid argument

Tags: c, debugging, lldb, apple-m1, macos-monterey

I am trying to debug a C executable compiled for arm64 on an Apple M1 MacBook Pro, running macOS Monterey. However, when I try to run the program in `lldb`, I receive the following error:

```
(lldb) run
error: process exited with status -1 (attach failed ((os/kern) invalid argument))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug an arm64 executable on a system running Rosetta, you need to explicitly run `lldb` within the arm64 architecture. To do this:

```
arch -arm64 lldb ./your-program
```